# haskell function gap that takes in list of elements and returns true if gap

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a haskell function that takes in a list of elements and returns true if there is a space and false if there is not.

Here is what I have, when running the test it returns all true. When the first 2 cases shuld be false.

```
gaps :: (Enum t, Eq t) => [t] -> Bool
gaps [] = False
gaps [x] = False
gaps (x:y:xs) = if y == (succ x) then gaps (y:xs) else True

gapsTests = [
          not $ gaps [1..10]
         ,not $ gaps "ABCD"
         ,gaps "ABD"
         ,gaps [1,2,3,5,6]
         ,gaps "ABBC"
        ]
```

Comment: Notice the `not` in front, so `not $ gaps [1..10]` will return `True` if there are no gaps.

Comment: so it should all return True? I didnt realize the not

Comment: Using not means you can verify all the tests using `and gapsTests` rather than something like `gapsTests == [False, False, True, True, True]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first two cases return `True` as well, since we use a `not $` in front. We thus check if there are *no* gaps for `[1..10]` and *no* gaps for `"ABCD"`, that holds in both cases:

```
gapsTests = [
    not $ gaps [1..10]   -- check if the list does not contain any gaps
  , not $ gaps "ABCD"    -- check if the list does not contain any gaps
  , gaps "ABD"           -- check if the list does contain any gaps
  , gaps [1,2,3,5,6]     -- check if the list does contain any gaps
  , gaps "ABBC"          -- check if the list does contain any gaps
  ]
```

This thus means that all items of your `gapsTests` should be `True`. If that is the case, the tests are successful.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid doing the recursion and case analysis yourself by just comparing to the list you expect to find, `[x..y]`:

```
gaps :: (Enum t, Eq t) => [t] -> Bool
gaps [] = False
gaps xs@(x:_) = not (and (zipWith (==) xs [x..]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`if A then B else True` is the same as `if not A then True else B` which is the same as `not A || B`.

You can thus rewrite your code as

```
gaps :: (Enum t, Eq t) => [t] -> Bool
gaps (x:y:xs)  =  (y /= succ x) || gaps (y:xs)
gaps _  =  False
```

Then,

```
> gaps [1..10]
False                         -- no gaps

> gaps "ABC"
False                         -- no gaps

> gaps ("ABD" ++ undefined)
True                          -- there's a gap here
```

The input is only visited for as many elements as needed to get a result. his is known as "lazy evaluation".